# Add text before time in tooltip

Tags: chart.js

My dataset is base on weekly data and I've configured the xAxes to only display the month and year (avoids having too many labels). Now I'd like to add text before the date in the tooltip. Here is the default TT:

[image]

How can I change the tooltip to read: Week ending: 25/03/18

[image]

I tried adding a tooltip callback, but couldn't modify the date, just the label.

```
options: {
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      type: 'time',
      position: 'bottom',
      time: {
        displayFormats: {'day': 'MM/YY'},
        tooltipFormat: 'DD/MM/YY',
        unit: 'month'
      }
    }]
  },
  tooltips: {
    callbacks: {
      label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
        var label = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label || ''
        if (label) {
          label = 'Week ending: ' + label
        }
        return label
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: see my answer below

Comment: What you mean by Weekending ?

Comment: The data point represents data accumulated over 7 days (a week). The tool tip only displays a single date. My intention is to make it clearer that the data is for the week, not just 1 day. I guess a clearer wording would be "Week ending on: d/m/y"

Comment: The more appropriate would be be Till Date instead of week ending..

Comment: Still I am not able to understand your problem.. Solution can be derived easily from callback function

Comment: Semantics aside, what is this easy solution? I've posted what I tried in the callback, but the addition is in the wrong place. I don't see the point in having the date listed twice, hence my question: How do I add text before the existing date in the tooltip?

Comment: Yes but it's better to upload pic of whole chart so I can really understand.. U can blur the sensitive info if any

Answer (score 0):

Below is a working Demo, But you can enhance the finding the weekend value even better because this doesn't hold good if the weekend value is greater than 30

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.js"></script>


<head>
  <title>Bar Chart</title>
  <style>
    canvas {
      -moz-user-select: none;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container" style="width: 100%;">
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  </div>
  <script>
    var MONTHS = ['January', 'February'];

    var barChartData = {
      labels: ['03/20/2018', '03/10/2018'],
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Dataset 1',
        borderWidth: 1,
        data: [
          1,
          2
        ]
      }, {
        label: 'Dataset 2',
        borderWidth: 1,
        data: [
          3,
          4
        ]
      }]

    };

    window.onload = function() {
      var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
      window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: barChartData,
        options: {
          responsive: true,
          legend: {
            position: 'top',
          },
          tooltips: {
            callbacks: {
                label: function(tooltipItems, data) {
                var xLabel = tooltipItems.xLabel;
                var dt = new Date(xLabel);
                
                var lastday = dt.getDate() - (dt.getDay() - 1) + 6;  
                    var label = "Weekend Is: "+lastday;
                    return label;
                }
            }
        },
          title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Chart.js Bar Chart'
          }
        }
      });

    };
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I'll edit my post to be more clear. The timestamp at the top of the TT is the end of the week. I want to go from:
dd/mm/yyyy to Weed ending: dd/mm/yyyy